# foreach en metodo con parametro generico

Tags: c#, foreach, genericos

hace poco rato me han mostrado aquí como podía definir un método con entrada de parámetros genéricos.
Lo he aplicado pero creo que algo estoy haciendo mal:

```
 public static async Task InsertaBatchProducts<T>(List<T> Articles) where T : class
 {
    Ccategoria cc = new Ccategoria();
    List<Product> productes = new List<Product>();
    if (Articles.GetType() == typeof(List<Cproduct>))
            {

                foreach (Cproduct s2p in Articles)
                {
                    Product p = new Product();
                    p.sku = s2p._codi;
                    p.name = s2p.name;
                    p.description = s2p.description;
                    p.categories = await cc.RetornaCategoriaBBDD(s2p);
                    productes.Add(p);
                }
            }
 }
```

Haciéndolo así el `Foreach` me genera el error: No se puede convertir el tipo 'T' en Con.Cproduct.
Cómo tengo que definir el iterador en el `foreach` para que me funcione?
muchas gracias.

Comment: Incluye más información que pueda darnos un mejor panorama para reproducir tu escenario, ¿Articles es una clase? ¿Una lista? ¿Una lista basada en Cproduct?

Comment: Lo he editado, disculparme, me he liado al copiar pegar...

Comment: Despreocúpate hermano, estás en casa, aquí todos nos damos un apoyo como podamos :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net no permite convertir el tipo T a ningún otra clase si no está definida en el método. Los métodos genéricos suelen emplearse para evitar el boxing y el unboxing que consume ciertos recursos. No obstante, tu for se puede arreglar así:

```
    public static async Task InsertaBatchProducts<T>(List<T> Articles) where T : Cproduct
 {
    Ccategoria cc = new Ccategoria();
    List<Product> productes = new List<Product>();
    if (Articles.GetType() == typeof(List<Cproduct>))
            {

                foreach (T s2p in Articles)
                {
                    
                    Cproduct oCproduct = (Cproduct) s2p;
                    Product p = new Product();
                    p.sku = oCproduct._codi;
                    p.name = oCproduct.name;
                    p.description = oCproduct.description;
                    p.categories = await cc.RetornaCategoriaBBDD(oCproduct);
                    productes.Add(p);
                }
            }
 }
```

Otra opción es establecer una herencia común.

```
public static async Task InsertaBatchProducts<T>(List<T> Articles) where T : ProductoPadre
     {
        Ccategoria cc = new Ccategoria();
        List<Product> productes = new List<Product>();
        if (Articles.GetType() == typeof(List<Cproduct>))
                {
    
                    foreach (T s2p in Articles)
                    {
                        
                        ProductoPadre oCproduct = (ProductoPadre) s2p;
                        Product p = new Product();
                        p.sku = oCproduct._codi;
                        p.name = oCproduct.name;
                        p.description = oCproduct.description;
                        p.categories = await cc.RetornaCategoriaBBDD(oCproduct);
                        productes.Add(p);
                    }
                }
     }
```

También puedes emplear dos tipos de parámetro:

```
 public static async Task InsertaBatchProducts<T1, T2>(List<T1> Articles, List<T2> Articles) where T1 : Cproduct where T2 : C2product
         {
            Ccategoria cc = new Ccategoria();
            List<Product> productes = new List<Product>();
            if (Articles.GetType() == typeof(List<Cproduct>))
                    {
        
                        foreach (T s2p in Articles)
                        {
                            
                            Cproduct oCproduct = (ProductoPadre) s2p;
                            Product p = new Product();
                            p.sku = oCproduct._codi;
                            p.name = oCproduct.name;
                            p.description = oCproduct.description;
                            p.categories = await cc.RetornaCategoriaBBDD(oCproduct);
                            productes.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (Articles.GetType() == typeof(List<C2product>))
                    {
        
                        foreach (T s2p in Articles)
                        {
                            
                            C2product oCproduct = (C2product) s2p;
                            Product p = new Product();
                            p.sku = oCproduct._codi;
                            p.name = oCproduct.name;
                            p.description = oCproduct.description;
                            p.categories = await cc.RetornaCategoriaBBDD(oCproduct);
                            productes.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
         }
```

Otra opción es definir una o varias interfaces ya que así el where te permite la recepción de más de una:

```
public static async Task InsertaBatchProducts<T>(List<T> Articles) where T : IProduct, ICsProduct
         {
            Ccategoria cc = new Ccategoria();
            List<Product> productes = new List<Product>();
            if (Articles.GetType() == typeof(List<ICsProduct>))
                    {
        
                        foreach (T s2p in Articles)
                        {
                            
                            ICsProduct oCproduct = (ICsProduct) s2p;
                            Product p = new Product();
                            p.sku = oCproduct._codi;
                            p.name = oCproduct.name;
                            p.description = oCproduct.description;
                            p.categories = await cc.RetornaCategoriaBBDD(oCproduct);
                            productes.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
         }
```

Aunque si sabes qué tipos te van a llegar por parámetro no parece necesario un método genérico. Te basta con la sobreescritura de métodos.

Comment: Este método, puede recibir dos tipos de Listas como parámetro List<Cproduct> o List<Cs2Product> y dependiendo de que tipo de objeto reciba, actuará de una o otra forma.
¿especificando en where T : Cproduct no podré pasar como parametro una lista Cs2Product?

Comment: He visto la edición ahora, muchísimas gracias.